# Увеличение максимального времени выполнения скрипта max_execution_time

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Если менять max_execution_time в php.ini, то при вызове `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');` пишет 0 .
Если ставить вручную в скрипте `ini_set('max_execution_time', '5');` , то пишет, что 5. Но скрипт не прекращает работу, если выполнить `sleep(15)`. Так же не работает `set_time_limit(5);`. В чем дело? Система - ubuntu. Самое интересное, что через openserver на винде все работает.
P.S. Так же изменил во max_execution_time во всех php.ini( для apache2, cli, fpm) - все равно не работает. Может кто знает, как решить проблему?

Comment: А php демон перезапускали?

Comment: Да, на всякий случай всю систему перезапускал)

Comment: PHP скрипт выполняю просто через консоль, не на хостинге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но скрипт не прекращает работу, если выполнить sleep(15)

Весь фокус в том, что так и должно быть. Об этом сказано в мануале [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
> max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
> itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
> of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
> database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
> time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
> where the measured time is real.

set_time_limit считает только время затраченное на выполнение скрипта, но не включает внешние вызовы. sleep тоже системный вызов, потому не участвует в подсчёте времени.

Это поведение отличается в windows от всех остальных систем.

Comment: Благодарю, действительно, sleep игнорирует) . Попробовал бесконечный цикл, выдает ошибку) Спасибо большое вам!